# Automatically registering targets with a target group in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, autoscaling

I have a AWS deployment setup like below.

An ELB which directs traffic to target-group 'abc-tg'
An auto-scaling group which scales the number of instances (with a given name tag)

I manually registered two targets to the target group, I am wondering if there is any configuration which automatically registers any newly spawned (by autoscaling) target to the target group 'abc-tg'

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a target group to the autoscaling configuration. After you attach a target group to an Auto Scaling group, Auto Scaling registers your targets with the target group for you when it launches them.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/attach-load-balancer-asg.html

Answer (score 0):

If the Loadbalancer ip(public) and the instance behind the loadbalancer are in the same avaiability zone, Autoscaling will create the instance automatically. You don't need to manually add. If you had to manually add the booting instance, something is wrong. Check the VPC and subnet of Loadbalancer and ASG networks.